# kendo vertical scroll functionality broken

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a list of 1000 items in the grid and the page size is set to 30. It seems the kendo vertical scroll functionality is broken.As a newbie i was not able to figure out exactly. The only way I can access the elements beyond the limit is to search via filter right now. Can some one help me out

```js
var grid = $scope.var.listViewWidget;

grid.setOptions({
    sortable: true,
    groupable: true,
    selectable: false,
    //pageable: true,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "name",
        template: kendo.template($("#tpl-SiteItem").html())
    }, {
        field: "letter",
        hidden: true,
        groupHeaderTemplate: "#= value #"
    }, {
        field: "Floor",
        hidden: true,
        groupHeaderTemplate: "#= value #"
    }]
});

});



sort: getDSSort(),
pageSize: $rootScope.sysSettings.siteSurvey_serverPaging ? 30 : 0,
serverGrouping: $rootScope.sysSettings.siteSurvey_serverPaging,
serverPaging: $rootScope.sysSettings.siteSurvey_serverPaging,
serverSorting: $rootScope.sysSettings.siteSurvey_serverPaging,
serverFiltering: $rootScope.sysSettings.siteSurvey_serverPaging
});
```

Comment: I wa trying to ident your code, but as you can see, the brakets doesn't really fit togeder.  Can you confirm if the sort / pageSize / serverGrouping .... are really outside the grid.setOptions?

Comment: the page sizing is outside of the grid.setOptions @ The_Black_Smurf

Comment: Then I think we're missing some code here... sort / pageSize / ... are part of an object definition but they seems to be floating out of nowhere in your sample code.